# a form with several entries in a cycle

Tags: python, html, flask, mysql-workbench

I have a form with several inputs and they are inside a for. What the for does is to find some data (id) and according to the amount of data, it creates several forms. What happens is that I want that from the web with a single button I can send all the information and is stored in a function that I created with python flask, but I do not know how to do. chatgpt gave me a suggestion but only sends me a form.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

```
 <tbody>
                        {% if data %}
                            {% for row in data %}
                                <tr>
                                    <form id="miFormulario{{row.Activo}}" action="{{ url_for('addUser') }}" method="POST">

                                        <!-- Campos ocultos para almacenar valores -->
                                        
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Activo" value="{{ row[0] }}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="NombreSala" value="{{ row[1] }}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="NombreExperiencia" value="{{ row[2] }}">

                                        <td>{{ row[0] if row[0] is defined else '' }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ row[1] if row[1] is defined else '' }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ row[2] if row[2] is defined else '' }}</td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 fecha-manual" name="Fecha">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <!-- Ingresar manualmente la información de estado -->
                                            <select style="width: 150px;" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" name="Estado">
                                                <option value="BUENA">Buena</option>
                                                <option value="REPARADA">Reparada</option>
                                                <option value="DESHABILITADA">Deshabilitada</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <!-- Ingresar manualmente la información de comentario -->
                                            <label for="comentario_manual"></label>
                                            <textarea id="comentario_manual" name="Comentario" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
                                        </td>
                                                                
                                    </form>
                                </tr>
                                
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- Botón de enviar -->
                <button id="miFormulario" class="btn btn-success " type="button">Enviar</button>
            </div>
```

with javascript create a script as suggested by chatgpt

```
 // Obtener el botón por su ID
            var botonEnviar = $("#botonEnviar");

            // Agregar un evento clic al botón
            botonEnviar.on("click", function () {
                // Enviar manualmente el formulario cuando se hace clic en el botón
                $("#miFormulario").submit();
            });
        });
```

but the result I get is this:('1190', 'escena', '2023-11-30', 'cartografia del cuerpo', 'BUENA', '')
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2023 08:50:55] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2023 08:50:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

It only shows the first form when I press the submit button from the web.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DetLt.png)

Comment: If you want everything submitted at the same time then you should use a single form with multiple inputs rather than multiple forms.